# SSIS Lower Case Thorn Delimiter Issue

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssis, etl, delimiter

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 SSIS and have written a package to ingest a DAT file (in standard Concordance delimited format - with a lower case thorn text delimiter "**þ**", and pilcrow column delimiter "¶" (ascii 244), and CR/LF row delimiter.

Not sure how this happens, where the delimiter itself gets imported into the SQL 2014 database receiving table:

[image: thorn delimiter issue]

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In the Flat file connection manager do the following:

1. Choose `{CR}{LF}` as **Row Delimiter**
2. Choose `¶` as **Column Delimiter**
3. Choose `þ` as **Text Qualifier**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response, Hadi, but that's what I've done above to get the error/issues as shown.  Not sure why...

Comment: @Craig this solution is working with me, check that there is no encoding mismatch between the `.DAT` file and the connection manager

Comment: @Craig can you provide a data sample?